# guardar en una celda distinta estoy usando ws.appendRow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo el siguiente código, el problema es que al enviarlo lo recibo todo dentro de una celda que puedo hacer para que se envíe, de manera que todas las líneas que produzcan se guarden en una nueva celda  de Google.

```
   var pedido ='';
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.Data.length; i++) {             
        pedido+=cart.Data[i].producto+"\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a agregar varias filas en una ejecución de tu función de Google Apps Script, `Sheet.appendRow` podría no ser la opción más eficiente e inclusive to podría generar errores de exceder el tiempo máximo de ejecución

En lugar de concatenar deberías crear un Array de Arrays (array 2D / bidimiensional)

La siguiente modificación de tu código crea una columna

```
var pedido = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cart.Data.length; i++) {             
    pedido.push([cart.Data[i].producto ]);
}
```

Luego para pasar los datos a la hoja de cálculo usa `Range.setValue(pedido)` (donde Range es un objeto de tipo Class Range). Puedes encontrar la última fila del rango de datos usando `Sheet.getLastRow()` (donde Sheet es un objeto de tipo Class Sheet).